# Merging multiple rows based on first column

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel with two columns (B & C) - Business case and solution, there will be multiple business cases which might have same solution, i want to merge it based on solution. Something like below -

```
BC1 Sol1
BC2 Sol2
BC3 Sol2
BC4 Sol3
BC5 Sol4
BC6 Sol4
BC7 Sol4
```

output should be -

```
BC1 Sol1
BC2, BC3 Sol2
BC4 Sol3
BC5, BC6, BC7 Sol4
```

i would like to do this in VBA and tried something like below -

```
LASTROW = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'get last row
For I = 0 To LASTROW Step 1
    For J = I + 1 To LASTROW Step 1
        If Cells(I, "C") = Cells(J, "C") Then
            Cells(I, "B") = Cells(I, "B") & "," & Cells(J, "B")
            Rows(J).Delete
        End If
    Next
Next
```

the above works, but is very slow when running on 1000 rows, i went through other questions similar to this but not good in VBA to mod that for above one. Can someone please help ?

Comment: using `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` before your loop and set it back to `True` after will most likely increase performance

Comment: Thanks for the comment, yah, i tried it. in addition to screen update i was also disabling events etc. But still it was slow. I saw some post solutions where variant type was used instead of looping through cells directly, not sure how i can use them here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have commented, using a variant array rather than looping the cells directly will speed this up enormously

To apply that here you could:

1. Determine the source data range, and copy that into an array
2. Create another array to contain the new data
3. Loop the source array, testing for the required patterns, and populate the destination array
4. Copy the new data back to the sheet, overwriting the old data

---

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim datSrc As Variant
    Dim datDst As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim rwOut As Long
    Dim str As String

    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    With ws
        Set rng = Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp))
        datSrc = rng.Value

        ReDim datDst(1 To UBound(datSrc, 1), 1 To UBound(datSrc, 2))
        rwOut = 1

        For i = 1 To UBound(datSrc, 1)
            str = datSrc(i, 1)
            If datSrc(i, 2) <> vbNullString Then
                For j = i + 1 To UBound(datSrc, 1)
                    If datSrc(i, 2) = datSrc(j, 2) Then
                        str = str & "," & datSrc(j, 1)
                        datSrc(j, 2) = vbNullString
                    End If
                Next
                datDst(rwOut, 1) = str
                datDst(rwOut, 2) = datSrc(i, 2)
                rwOut = rwOut + 1
            End If
        Next
        rng = datDst
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for solution and explanation! In addition to the approach provided above, i just have to empty blank rows in-between using -     Range("B:B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete